# Need help for Filtering the data in sql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

i have  a table that contain `s.no` `Id` and `Amount` and `accCode`.

```
  s.no-------------id--------------Amount--------accCode
   1----------------2---------------20-------------2.1
   2----------------1---------------30-------------2.1
   3--------------- 5---------------20-------------3.1
   4----------------1---------------30-------------2.1
   5----------------3---------------40-------------3.1
   6----------------2---------------20-------------2.1
```

i need all the record that have a common `Amount` and `accCode` and `id`. In this case i need to show the data of S.NO 2 and 4, and also 1 and 6   as they have  similar value. If Possible it would be better the `similar data come orderly`. Is this one  possible through Sql? Please give some hints i am stuck with this one.thaks in advance.

Comment: similar data come orderly: what do you mean more precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be, assuming that your table is named "test"

```
select t1.*, t2.[s.no] as MatchSNo from test t1, test t2
where t1.id = t2.id and t1.amount = t2.amount
and t1.acccode = t2.acccode and t1.[s.no] <> t2.[s.no]
order by t1.id, t1.Amount, t1.accCode, [s.no]
```

Comment: change `<>` to `<` and you only get each result once (rather than getting 1,6 and 6,1 as two separate rows).